# How to get a particular branch of github project in one line command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, github

Let's say that I have a rails plugin called "`wipy`" on GitHub. It has a master branch and it has production branch. I am using Rails 2.3.10.

I need to install `production` branch of this plugin. This is what I do currently:

```
git clone git://github.com/nadala/demo.git
git co -b production origin/production
cp -rv wipy ~/my_project/vendor/
```

I could do:

```
ruby script/plugin install git://github.com/nadal/wipy.git
```

However I do not know how to pass an indicator that I want production branch.
I tried following but it did not work:

```
ruby script/plugin install git://github.com/nadal/wipy.git  --branch production
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this [blog post help](http://www.paulsturgess.co.uk/articles/show/91-how-to-install-a-ruby-on-rails-plugin-from-a-specific-git-repository-branch)?

> Recently I needed to install the Rails 2.3 stable version of the exception notification plugin and so I needed to specify a particular branch in the git repository.

```
script/plugin install git://github.com/rails/exception_notification.git -r 2-3-stable
```

> **The `-r` option allows you to identifiy the specific branch you're after**.

In your case:

```
ruby script/plugin install git://github.com/nadal/wipy.git  -r production
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ruby script/plugin install git://github.com/nadal/wipy.git 
cd vendor/plugins/wipy
git checkout production
```